# How to pass selected parameters to a form action url via jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been searching a lot here and in Google about how to pass selected parameters to the action from URL as I prefer. But I don't have any idea how to do it. The code that I created doesn't meet the purpose since my level is simple in Javascript!

My code:

```js
$('#search-filter').on('submit', function() {

  var $this = $(this),
    getValue = $this.attr('action') + $('.uk-radio').val();
  $this.attr('action', getValue);
  $this.submit();

});
```

```css
#search-filter {
  padding: 40px;
}

#search-filter .uk-form-icon {
  padding: 0 10px;
  right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="search-filter" class="uk-margin-medium" action="https://example.com/search" target="_top">
  <h4 class="search-title">Search Filter</h4>
  <div class="search-input">
    <div class="uk-margin uk-grid-small uk-child-width-auto uk-grid">
      <div class="filters-title">Level:</div>
      <label><input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="level" value="beginner"> Beginner</label>
      <label><input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="level" value="intermediate"> Intermediate</label>
      <label><input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="level" value="advanced"> Advanced</label>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-margin uk-grid-small uk-child-width-auto uk-grid">
      <div class="filters-title">Type:</div>
      <label><input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="type" value="theorie"> Theorie</label>
      <label><input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="type" value="practical"> Practical</label>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-margin">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-horizontal-select">Select a category:</label>
      <div class="uk-form-controls">
        <select class="uk-select" id="form-horizontal-select">
          <option value="category1">Category 01</option>
          <option value="category2">Category 02</option>
          <option value="category3">Category 03</option>
          <option value="category4">Category 04</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary">Filter</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The output I have got:

```
https://example.com/searchbeginnerbeginnerbeginner?level=beginner&type=practical
```

The output I really need:

```
https://example.com/search?label=beginner+practical+category01&max-results=4
```

As you see there are three parameters within **+** sing after a **label=** then a parameter **max-results** after **&** sign.

There is any method to get such as this link above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you shouldn't have to do that - a form does that automatically.

Comment: Use `$this.serialize()` to get all the form field values.

Comment: Where is `max-results` in the form?

Comment: I don't see how you're get the result you're getting. `$('.uk-radio').val()` will just return the value of the first input with that class, not all of them. At a minimum you need to use `$('.uk-radio:checked')` to select only the selected options, but you still need to loop over them and combine them.

Comment: You don't need `$this.submit()`, that happens automatically if you don't call `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @Barmar the max-results is an additional parameter that I can use as a string something like that "example.com/search?label=' + values + '&max-results=12".

Comment: But your example code doesn't do that, so how is it getting that as the actual result?

Comment: Hi guys,
I have used another method using pure js and is working fine right now see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/infinyteam/LdgLyL2t/), now I just need to get the select options value as a variable getSelect that I was defined before, anybody knows how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following for your JavaScript

```
$('#search-filter').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var queryParams = 'label=' + $('input[name="level"]').val() 
                               + '+' + $('input[name="type"]').val()
                               + '+' + $('#form-horizontal-select').val()
                     + '&max-results=4';
    window.open('https://example.com/search?'+queryParams, "_blank");
});
```

If you want the category values to be category**0***, then you must also update the option values to

```
<select class="uk-select" id="form-horizontal-select">
    <option value="category01">Category 01</option>
    <option value="category02">Category 02</option>
    <option value="category03">Category 03</option>
    <option value="category04">Category 04</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi @GSSwain, Thank you so much for help :)

Answer (score 2):

To get select option value you can use the following coding:

```
var selectBox=document.getElementById("form-horizontal-select");
getSelect=selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I have done and it works so nice, Thanks!!